# SELECT between 7am and 7am next day

Tags: mysql

i want to count how many values of 1 and 0 i have between 7am and 7am next day.

think here a bar that opens at 10am but closes next day at 7am, they want their 'report' to be for this specific day.

so all data before 7am needs to be added to the day before.

```
SELECT DATE(delivered), COUNT(*) total, 
sum(case when isbag = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CloakCount,
sum(case when isbag = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) BagCount
FROM Wardrobe_CloakTable GROUP BY DATE(delivered)
```

this will give me almost what i want, the problem is that i need to count all those data before 7am, to the day before.

Comment: just want to mention that delivered is a datetime field in my database

Comment: You want count for **CloakCount** and **BagCount** ?

Comment: yes, correct. when isbag = 0 its a cloak .. when isbag = 1 its a bag.. but the main problem is that it needs to be between 7am and 7am next day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN HOUR(delivered) < 7
   THEN CONCAT(DATE(DATE_ADD(delivered, INTERVAL -1 day)), ' 07:00:00')
   ELSE CONCAT(DATE(delivered), ' 07:00:00')
   END as startTime, 
CASE WHEN HOUR(delivered) < 7
   THEN CONCAT(DATE(delivered), ' 07:00:00')
   ELSE CONCAT(DATE(DATE_ADD(delivered, INTERVAL 1 day)), ' 07:00:00')
   END as endTime, 
COUNT(*) total, 
sum(case when isbag = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CloakCount,
sum(case when isbag = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) BagCount
FROM Wardrobe_CloakTable GROUP BY startTime, endTime;
```

Comment: That is just brilliant.. Gives me exactly what i want.! counts of total/bags/cloaks on dates with informations on.. will test further but thanks!